# deleting " from variable

Tags: powershell

So I have a VERY simple code below ... the commented out section is my problem area. I basically want to ask for a full file path ...  I know that Windows will attach " but the rest of my code requires no quotation marks to work.  So I basically want to take $Path and strip the " marks off of it and call the resulting path.   Can anyone help please?

edit: or even better...  how can I adjust my code that I can call the $Path with quotation makes (for paths with spaces) … and still work?  Either solution would be appreciated.

```
Write-Host ' '
$Path = Read-Host 'Please provide full path for file deletion'
# path = path.replace("\"", "");
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

Comment: In PowerShell, the default escape sequence character is a backtick \`, not a slash \\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works to remove the quotes from the string

```
Write-Host ' '
$Path = Read-Host 'Please provide full path for file deletion'
$Path = $Path.Replace('"','');
$Path
```

Comment: Man, I really thought I tried that... but I guess not...  at any rate.. that worked! thank you. -- oooh!  I see my mistake!  Thanks again!